# Prove that in a nilpotent group every normal subgroup of prime order is contained in the center.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, nilpotent-groups

> Prove that in a nilpotent group every normal subgroup of prime order is contained in the center.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Using for example the upper central series

$$1=Z_0\lhd Z_1:=Z(G)\lhd Z_2\lhd\ldots\lhd Z_n=G$$

show that  $\;1\neq N\lhd G\implies N\cap Z(G)\neq 1\;$

Comment: The result that you told is a standard result. I know it. But with it, how can we prove the main result?

Comment: Use now that the order of $\;N\;$ is a **prime** and the above...that's all!

Comment: Nice work, and great follow up comment, too! +1

Comment: Thanks @amWhy. I dealt a lot with groups, nilpotent and all, while in graduate school: now it pays! :)

Comment: Hmmm...I have yet to be "paid" for my work here at MSE! ;-)

Comment: We have the order of $N$ is a prime, and $N\cap Z(G)\neq 1$. But why $N$ is contained in $Z(G)$?

Comment: Can you explain more precisely?

Comment: Hmmm...take $\;1\neq x\in N\cap Z(G)\;$, @user110834: what is $\;\langle x\rangle\;$ ??

Comment: I need more details. May you give me?

Comment: @user110834, what's the order of **any** non trivial element in a group of prime order?!?

Comment: Ehm, of course. I forgot the order of $N$ is a prime. :) Thank you very much.